# linked server connection error in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

When I tried to execute query I got the below error.

```
SELECT   *    
FROM OPENQUERY([TESTORACLE], 'select *   from TESTTABLE')
```

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "TESTORACLE".

I have created DSN and used below query to create linked server.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname    = 'TESTORACLE'
,@useself       = 'False'
,@locallogin    = NULL
,@rmtuser       = 'USERNAME'
,@rmtpassword   = 'PASSWORD';

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
@server        = 'TESTORACLE'
,@srvproduct    = 'ORCLELINK'
,@provider      = 'MSDASQL'
,@datasrc       = 'ORCLELINK'
```

After that I tested the linked server and it **worked fine**. 
When I execute a query it throws access denied exception so I enable **Allow In process** to the provider.

After that it throws above error and the test connection also not works.

Not sure why the connection fails when I enable **Allow in process.**

Please help me to resolve the error.

Thanks,

Comment: you should recreate the linked server with Allow in process optiion checked. Try it.

Comment: But enabling allow in process cause the connection issue.  One thing it worked yesterday and I can communicate with Oracle server.  The  issue is only occurs on Today morning. not sure what happens in between.

Comment: @GeorgeK how to enable **Allow in process** in the creation script. please

Comment: why have not you created special provider for Oracle and use MSDASQL?

Comment: @GeorgeK sorry I'm a noob here. Could you please explain in detail.

Comment: @GeorgeK  Thanks for your valuable time. I have installed both sql server and oracle on same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install the correct Oracle drivers.  You want the latest version of the Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC), and you want the XCopy deployment.  They are available here:
64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

One you download and unzip this into a folder run the following command from that folder:

```
C:\Users\dbrowne\Downloads\ODAC121010Xcopy_x64>.\install.bat oledb c:\oracle\odac64 odac64 true
```

Then you need to add two folders to your system path:

```
c:\oracle\odac64 and c:\oracle\odac64\bin
```

Then you must reboot for the system path change to be visible by services like `SQL Server`.

After reboot you're ready to create and test the linked server.
First configure the Oracle OleDB provider to run inside the SQL Server process, and configure it to accept parameters.

```
exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'AllowInProcess', 1

exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'DynamicParameters', 1
```

Then create the linked server definition.  Instead of a TNSNames alias, use an EZConnect identifier.  Here I'm specifying an IP address and a SID to connecto to an Oracle Express instance running on a VM:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver N'MyOracle', 'Oracle', 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'//172.16.8.119/xe', N'FetchSize=2000', ''
exec master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyOracle', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='MyOracle', @useself=N'FALSE', @rmtuser=N'system',@rmtpassword='xxxxxx'
```

Now you're ready to test.  You configured the linked server for 'rpc out' so we can send a simple passthrough query to test connectivity:

```
exec ('select 1 a from dual') at MyOracle
```

That's it.

Comment: I have installed both sql server and oracle on same machine.  Will it work?

Comment: @User12345, I believe there is no reason it wouldn't